# strcpy System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, c++-cli

When I get to the strcpy line,  I am getting

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred. 
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. 
This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.


char* str; char* out;
str = (char*) Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(Parms["AVI"]).ToPointer();  
strcpy(out, str);  
Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr(str));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory and point `out` to that memory. As it is right now, `out` points to some random memory location.

Comment: What should be the length of the memory allocated?

Comment: Length should be `(strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 0):

After you set str, but before you copy it to out:

```
char* out = (char*)malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));

if (out != NULL) {
    strcpy(out, str);
}
```

As you need some sort of buffer to copy into. Be sure to free(out) when you're done with it.

Comment: `sizeof(char)==1` on *every* platform

Comment: @qehgt Yup, just trying to be explicit and clear about what I'm doing if OP is curious.

Comment: Line of malloc says error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'

Comment: @bestnagi Ah, you'll need to cast it. Normally I write the casts out explicitly from mallocs, but I was recently given reason not to. I'll have to reconsider once again, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

[How to convert from System::String* to Char* in Visual C++](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259)

"Method 3" looks very straightforward. No need for manual deallocation of memory.